# how add marks to the line plot with different x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a line plot for a health data. The data looks like this:

[image]

and it can be build with following codes:

```
#Data
Days<-c("-6","-6","-6","-1","-1","-1","1","6","6","6","13","13","13","16","20","20","20","24","28","28","28","44","44","44")
Event<-c("","","","","","","H","","H","","","","","H","","","","H","","","","","","")
Item <-c("DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP")
Result <- c("100","68","149","98","80","142","","98","88","142","110","72","160","","102","69","159","","99","82","136","97","84","144")
#Dataframe
Sample.data <- data.frame( Days, Event, Item, Result,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to make a line plot with event marked on the line or the bottom. Sth looks like following:
[image]

or
[image]

what should I do? In the graph, I also addes a line y=120, and y=80 for normal blood pressure line.  The tricky part is not every event reported at the same date item test was taken.

Answer (score 0):

Your data do not have any `"P"` events but I guess you need something like this ?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(type.convert(Sample.data)) + 
  aes(Days, Result, group = Item, color = Item, label = Event) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 5, color = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I could not plot the event, so I manually add it . so that just a type of plot that I want to get . .The problem is i only see 'H' when it has a !na item. where is the `H' on day 1, 16, 24?